# How do I modify a datetime hash in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hashmap

I have a hash like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"yYl/Nts0KRktqjR5K7vYXf1jrOyRJmQOtaF7lPMIeZQ=",
 "meeting"=>{"name"=>"Robsbaun",
 "start_at(3i)"=>"4",
 "start_at(2i)"=>"10",
 "start_at(1i)"=>"2013",
 "start_at(4i)"=>"11",
 "start_at(5i)"=>"15",
 "end_at(1i)"=>"2013",
 "end_at(2i)"=>"10",
 "end_at(3i)"=>"4",
 "end_at(4i)"=>"19",
 "end_at(5i)"=>"15",
 "room_id"=>"1",
 "user_id"=>"2"},
 "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

And I want to set the same values for both `end_at(2i)` and `start_at(2i)` and `end_at(3i)` and `start_at(3i)`.

How can I do that in Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4?

I already tried something like:

```
meeting_params[":end_at(3i)"] = meeting_params[":start_at(3i)"]
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ugh. I'd STRONGLY recommend NOT using a `"✓"` for your flag whether it's a `utf8`. Use a boolean `true`/`false`, or at least use nil/not-nil. Your logic for testing it will be cleaner: `if hash['utf8']` vs. `if hash['utf8'] == "✓"`, and it will make it more compatible with various ORMs, DBMs and database schemas, which already understand that true/false or nil/not-nil map to standard "is"/"is not" conditional tests in the database.

Comment: I don't know how to change that... But thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Directly changing the value should work, it's just a hash. Your syntax isn't quite right though. Assuming it comes in as `params`:

```
params['meeting']['end_at(3i)'] = params['meeting']['start_at(3i)']
```

You're trying to combine symbols and strings - just stick to one or the other.

Comment: Just to be totally sure... `end_at(3i)` and `start_at(3i)` are the same in the hash you posted, have you definitely tried this on a hash where those values differ?

Comment: Yes, in my form I only show the start_at on a date_select. I changed the day for like 12 (start_at(3i)=12), and the end_at get the Time.now, (so end_at(3i) would be equals to 4). In my controller I do:

    params['meeting']['end_at(3i)'] = params['meeting']['start_at(3i)']

But for some reason both end_at and start_at goes to Time.now, if I don't try to do this, the controller works right, and it saves start_at(3i) with 12